# if i have T&& temp = std::move(other); then use this on a function that accepts T by value

Tags: c++11, move, move-semantics

so let's say i have a following function:

```
void foo(std::string strParam) // pass-by-value
{
    // function-body
}
```

so strParam of foo(string) will either be created via copy (if arg was lvalue) or move (if arg was rvalue).

as everybody knows,

```
foo("blah"); // rvalue; so string move constructor invoked for strParam.
```

versus,

```
string bar = "blah";
foo(bar); // lvalue; so string copy constructor invoked for strParam.
```

again,

```
string bar = "blah";
foo(move(bar)); // xvalue; so move constructor.
```

and for *named* rvalue reference variable

```
string &&temp = // can be whatever
foo(temp); // *named* rvalue reference IS a lvalue; so copy constructor.
```

so i guess what that means is,

```
string &&movedBar = move(bar);
foo(movedBar); // it actually invokes copy constructor.
```

so invoking,

```
foo(move(bar))
```

is different from

```
string&& movedBar = move(bar);
foo(movedBar)
```

because one is unnamed rvalue reference (xvalue) and other is named rvalue reference (lvalue)

that's right, right?

Comment: In `string&& movedBar = move(bar)` `&&` stands for a [universal reference][0] [0]:http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: A named object is considered an lvalue. To propagate the *rvalue-ness* of the object you have to cast to an rvalue (i.e `std::move()`).

Comment: @erenon it's not a universal reference (even in the link's definition), and even if it was, it doesn't matter - it gets deduced to lvalue ref or rvalue ref and in either case, next line treats it as a lvalue - it would've been a universal reference if its type was auto&& (or involved type deduction T in templates); and even if i did use auto&& as its type (if i wrote it auto && movedBar = move(bar)), type gets deduced as string&& as rvalue reference, but it's a named rvalue reference, so it's a lvalue

Comment: @0x499602D2 I find it confusing to talk about the value category of objects. *Value category* is a property of expressions. Hence, the *id-expression* `movedBar` is an lvalue, and the function-call-expression `move(bar)` is an rvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One correction:

```
foo("blah"); // rvalue; so string move constructor invoked for strParam.
```

This *actually* invokes the `std::string` constructor that takes a `const char*` and not the `std::string` move constructor. That is the only `std::string` constructor in the overload set - everything else would involve more than one user-defined conversion.

On every other point, you are correct. To summarize:

```
foo("blah"); // calls string constructor that takes a const char*
foo(bar); // calls string copy ctor
foo(move(bar)); // calls string move ctor

string&& movedBar = move(bar);
foo(movedBar); // calls copy ctor
```

**Update**: As [Tobias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244255/if-i-have-t-temp-stdmoveother-then-use-this-on-a-function-that-accepts/28246064#comment44858936_28246064) points out in the comments, `foo("blah")` will actually call *two* constructors, as if it were actually `foo(string("blah"))`. First a temporary string is constructed from `"blah"` and that temporary is moved into `strParam`. However that second move will probably be elided, since `string strParam(string("blah"))` is redundant. This can be verified by `delete`-ing the move constructor of a custom widget or compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Or, as I like to look at it, we were both correct. The `const char*` is invoked *and* the string move constructor is invoked (~ish?).

Comment: It seems that the call `foo("blah")` requires the `const char*` constructor as well as the move constructor. However, the move constructor *may* then be elided. I tried this by rewriting the code with `std::string` replaced by a custom `Widget` class which has a `= delete`ed move-constructor.